# Issue when trying to run Node from Foreman on Lion - `exec': Permission denied error

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku, osx-lion, foreman

I've followed the guide on Heroku's website to get a node server running using foreman:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js

I can successfully start up the node server if I load it directly, but as soon as I use Foreman in the Procfile, it errors with the following...

```
My-MacBook-Air:myDirectory digiguru$ foreman start
13:25:26 web.1     | started with pid 29046
13:25:26 web.1     | /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:38:in `exec': Permission denied - /usr/local/foreman/bin/runner (Errno::EACCES)
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:38:in `fork_with_io'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:32:in `fork'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:32:in `fork_with_io'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:44:in `run_process'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:19:in `run'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:64:in `with_environment'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:18:in `run'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:17:in `chdir'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:17:in `run'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile_entry.rb:17:in `spawn'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile_entry.rb:15:in `map'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile_entry.rb:15:in `spawn'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:63:in `spawn_processes'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:61:in `each'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:61:in `spawn_processes'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:45:in `start'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:28:in `start'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
13:25:26 web.1     |    from /usr/bin/foreman:15
13:25:26 web.1     | process terminated
13:25:26 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Is there anything I can do to give Forman permission? I've tried `sudo foreman start`, but to no avail.

I am running in ruby version 1.9.3 (upgraded from version 1.8.7 installed on lion by default).

**UPDATE**

Running `sudo foreman start` after `@user658619` installing heruko and foreman from ruby gems, we get...

```
/Users/digiguru/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find foreman (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/digiguru/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/digiguru/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
    from /Users/digiguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/foreman:18:in `<main>'
```

My environment...

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/digiguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/digiguru/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/digiguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/digiguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
     - /Users/digiguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Are you able to start up node using exactly the command you've described in the Procfile?

Comment: so the command "node web.js" works when I'm in the correct directory,  the profile is simply "web: node web.js" which foreman checks correctly when running "foreman check".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to get it working I had unfortunatley mucked up my installations by having a mix of rubies and gems some of which required SUDO, some that didn't.

Fortunately the good people of the internet have solved this problem for you with a tool called RVM

> RVM lets you deploy each project with its own completely self-contained and dedicated environment--from the specific version of ruby, all the way down to the precise set of required gems to run your application. Having a precise set of gems also avoids the issue of version conflicts between projects, which can cause difficult-to-trace errors and hours of hair loss.

http://beginrescueend.com/

**First download RVM**

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

You'll want to open a new terminal window after doing this.

**Clean up.** If you have weirdly installed gems you'll want to remove them. Go to your root directory and sudo get rid of them. You can see all of them with the `gem list` command

```
cd 
sudo gem list
sudo gem uninstall foreman heroku
```

**Install a ruby.** You should do this in the subdirectory of your application. I chose 1.9.3

```
cd myApp
rvm install 1.9.3
```

**Add any gems you need.** For me that was just foreman and heroku.

```
cd myApp
gem install foreman heroku
```

Seemed to work a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem today. Did you install heroku thru heroku-toolbelt.pkg??

Try use gem to reinstall heroku and foreman.

```
sudo gem install heroku foreman
```

Comment: I didn't upgrade ruby to 1.9.3, I use default version on lion.

Comment: Okay - i've got it working. You shouln't use "sudo gem install" - it doesn't allow you to control the installation. Instead install without sudo. That way you can swap the profile later using rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In Procfile, do

```
web: node ./bin/www
```